# Login to the MVC 5 ASP.NET template Web Application fails when moved from the root folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I used the ASP.NET Web Application template to create a new "Single Page Application" with "Authentication: Individual User Accounts". It will run with the default settings without any problem.

If I don't deploy the application to the root folder of the web server the authentication fails. The culprit is in the app.viewmodel.js file where the following code can be found:

```
self.addViewModel = function (options) {
    var viewItem = new options.factory(self, dataModel),
        navigator;

    // Add view to AppViewModel.Views enum (for example, app.Views.Home).
    self.Views[options.name] = viewItem;

    // Add binding member to AppViewModel (for example, app.home);
    self[options.bindingMemberName] = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!dataModel.getAccessToken()) {
            // The following code looks for a fragment in the URL to get the access token which will be
            // used to call the protected Web API resource
            var fragment = common.getFragment();

            if (fragment.access_token) {
                // returning with access token, restore old hash, or at least hide token
                window.location.hash = fragment.state || '';
                dataModel.setAccessToken(fragment.access_token);
            } else {
                // no token - so bounce to Authorize endpoint in AccountController to sign in or register
                window.location = "/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
            }
        }

        return self.Views[options.name];
    });
```

The line where `window.location = "/Account..."` redirects the browser to an URL offset at the root directory. Unfortunately just hard coding this to the new folder instead (which I would like to avoid anyway) does not solve the problem entirely.

The redirect seems to work at first but behind the scenes in the `AccountController.cs`file 
`Authorize()`is called which in turn calls `AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity)` and somehere there is magic going on. There is a redirect to `http://localhost/foo/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=...` and we're back where we started.

I am probably missing the obvious. I'd appreciate any pointers.

It's very easy to replicate. Just create a new web app with the default settings and then go into project properties and change the "Project Url" to something like `http://localhost:49725/foo` which moves the app to a new folder called "foo".

Comment: Did you use the IIS tools to create a new virtual directory, or are you just trying to move the site to an arbitrary folder?

Comment: In the example above it's all done from within Visual Studio 2013 ("Project Url" -> "Create Virtual Directory") but the issue remains on a "real" IIS using the IIS server GUI to install the application. The problem is with the redirect somehow :( . It seem the template assumes you're running the app on the root ("/").

Comment: I have same problem, did you found a workaround?

Comment: Facing same problem in MVC5 VS2017 :/ Any news about this topic?

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing same problem, the change I did was:

1. In the file app.viewmodel.js I added a new parameter (returnUrl):

   ```
   // no token - so bounce to Authorize endpoint in AccountController to sign in or register
   window.location = "/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=" 
       + encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash) 
       + "&returnUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location);
   ```
2. In the method `ValidateClientRedirectUri` of class `ApplicationOAuthProvider` I read this parameter and set as the return url:

   ```
   public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
   {
       if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
       {
           Uri expectedRootUri;
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Query["returnUrl"]))
           {
               expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Query["returnUrl"]);
           }
           else
           {
               expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");
           }

           if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
           {
               context.Validated();
           }
           else if (context.ClientId == "web")
           {
               var expectedUri = new Uri(context.Request.Query["returnUrl"]);
               context.Validated(expectedUri.AbsoluteUri);
           }
       }

       return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
   }
   ```

Comment: I needed to replace the "/" with "/foo/" to be able to deploy my app to http://localhost/foo -- I was scratching my head as to where the redirect to root was. Your solution helped -- thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The solution for this is to open the app.viewmodel.js and locate the line that reads

```
/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state="
```

and change it to match the path of your subfolder

```
/YOUR_SITE/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state="
```